Somethings lead to the answer
I wanted to see if my group of 8 long-time online friends, some of which had the same nationality and some not, would be clever enought to figure out where I've hidden a treasure somewhere in the world, so I arranged a puzzle for them. I sent them a message, in a group chat, of unique flight routes they must take in order to find the treasure.
I wrote:


My eb friend, you must first fly to ge and then to th and then to xy. Positions: (BR-MM-TL)
My th friend, you must first fly to da and then to jf and then to xy. Positions: (TL-TM-TR)
My da friend, you must first fly to ge and then to si and then to xy. Positions:  (TM-MM-BM)
My kd friend, you must first fly to si and then to eb and then to xy. Positions:  (BL-BM-BR)
My jf friend, you must first fly to dg and then to eb and then to xy. Positions:  (TR-MR-BR)
My other kd friend, you must first fly to ge and then to jf and then to xy. Positions:  (BL-MM-TR)
My other th friend, you must first fly to ac and then to kd and then to xy. Positions:  (TL-ML-BL)
My ac friend, you must first fly to ge and then to dg and then to xy. Positions:  (ML-MM-MR)

xy, of course, represents other letters but when you figured out what two letters they represent, have in mind the treasure is actually located in preciely "xy" and not the other one you might think.
See you there in some weeks, I'll be there too. Good luck!

In which small location do they all meet and get the treasure?

The treasure is in ...

 ... Macau.

The two-letter destinations ...

 ... are ISO 3166-1 country codes, but reversed:

da → ad Andorra
eb → be Belgium
ac → ca Canada
kd → dk Denmark
ge → eg Egypt
jf → fj Fiji
rg → gr Grenada
th → ht Haiti
si → is Iceland

The positions ...

 ... are positions in a 3×3 grid indicated by Top / Middle / Bottom and Left / Middle / Right.
The filled in grid is:

 ht     ad     fj 

 ca     eg     gr 

 dk     is     be 

The "flights" ...

 .. are actually sums; the destination is the result of summing the origin and stop-overs.

 Note that the first letters of the countries and their codes conveniently span the first nine letters A–I. So let's replace the countries with the respective digits 1 to 9:

 8     1     6 

 3     5     7 

 4     9     2 

 It's magic! In this magic square each row, column and main diagonal – or, for that matter, each of the flights – have a sum of 15.

The destination xy:

 So we need a country that starts with the fifteenth letter, O. Luckily, there is only one sovereign state that starts with O, Oman with the country code om.

 Since all codes in the itinerary are reversed, om correponds to yx. The final destination is xy, which must be mo or Macau.

 (At least I hope so. If anything, it's easier to dig up Macau's 45 square miles for treasure than Oman's 120,000.)


Ah this is probably it! Wouldn’t have guessed a magic square was involved.

That's where it is, well done!

Title was a hint too (sound like rot13"fhz")

Anything with a magic square is cool, but i don't see how you concluded "So we need a country that starts with the fifteenth letter, O." When i think "small location", i don't think country. And why the 15th letter?

@jlee PN’s puzzles often requires a lot of trial and error, where the next step is not alluded to at all in the puzzle. Like here you could also ask why  convert half of the letters into numbers? Why convert them at all? Why form a magic square? I don’t think that is a bad thing though.

@pdt To me, especially since they are already in a 3x3, the conversion to numbers is fair game. It's just the 15th letter thing.

@Jlee because I think the first letters of the reversed iso code corresponds to a number using the A1Z26 cipher.

@Jlee You can see the top line as h+a+f = o

@JLee,  Copied: "My && friend, you must first fly to %% and then to ## and then to xy.", "I sent them a message, in a group chat, of unique flight routes they must take in order to find the treasure."

@JLee: I agree that "We need a country with O" was a bit fast-forwarding, but in addition to what fellow puzzlers have commented, there was one thing that made me sure this was right: One of the irrefutable facts of puzzledom is that there is only one country that starts with O.
